# Duplicate output file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to run a react-native project using the command `react-native run-ios` but I'm getting the following errors:

```
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.app/EvilIcons.ttf':
1) Target 'Humboi' (project 'Humboi') has copy command from '/Users/prikshetsharma/Desktop/Humboi/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/EvilIcons.ttf' to '/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.app/EvilIcons.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Humboi' (project 'Humboi'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”


Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.app/Entypo.ttf':
1) Target 'Humboi' (project 'Humboi') has copy command from '/Users/prikshetsharma/Desktop/Humboi/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Entypo.ttf' to '/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.app/Entypo.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Humboi' (project 'Humboi'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
... (and so on)

warning: duplicate output file '/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.app/Feather.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Humboi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.build/Script-725F34421484E3F6E70FFBB5.sh (in target 'Humboi' from project 'Humboi')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.app/FontAwesome.ttf' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/prikshetsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Humboi-hjbrwqprmopoeybrdkwevgblfvis/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Humboi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Humboi.build/Script-725F34421484E3F6E70FFBB5.sh (in target 'Humboi' from project 'Humboi')
...(and so on)
```

How to fix the errors and the warnings?

Answer (score 27):

**Go to Xcode project:**

1. Select project.
2. Get "Build Phases" section.
3. Tap "Copy Bundle Resources"
4. Delete .ttf fonts.

For full installation of [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) follow this guide:
[React Native Vector Icons](https://youtu.be/B75yZwYS4z8)

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, how did you set that opacity on Xcode?

Comment: No problem, It's system preference. What is your macos version?

Comment: Xcode 13 with Monterey, should be about the same as Big Sur

Comment: Yes. I also update mine to Monterey. I think it's related with accessibility settings: System Preferences > Accessibility > Display . There is a checkbox of Reduce transparency. If that is not checked then it should looks more transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Because it happens by running this same file from bundle resources and pod resources

So you just `open xcode -> your_project.xcodeproj -> click project folder -> build phases -> open copy bundle resources -> remove the error formed duplicate files` only. don't remove all the files like if it is in .ttf format. check your error log and remove it carefully. because you may configured any custom fonts or files in copy bundle resources

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue recently. it took me two days to solves. i was very tired then i found a clear cut solution:

Open your_project.xcodeproj in xcode. Click on the root folder then;
`build Phases -> (CP) Copy Pod Resources -> Output file lists` remove all files from it, because these file lists creating the duplication error.

Now run: `npm run ios` your will rebuild and run.